# Where is the neo4j slow query log?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to monitor the execution-time of my neo4j-cypher-queries, but I cant find the log-file for that. Even google did not help.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some config options to log query slower than a threshold, e.g.

```
dbms.querylog.enabled=true
dbms.querylog.filename=data/log/queries.log
dbms.querylog.max_archives=10
dbms.querylog.threshold=0
```

If you set the threshold to 0, each and every query is logged. Checkout out the section in the reference manual: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html

Comment: The format of parameters has changed to `dbms.logs.query.*`
Also, there's a mention that the feature is only available in the enterprise edition.